# Imitiating the Appium Inspector 'Refresh' button functionality in code? (Java)

Tags: appium, pom, elements

is there a way for us to refresh the application's elements present in the DOM? similar to the way you refresh the elements using the Appium Inspector's 'Refresh' button?
[image: Imitate the functionality of this button]

`driver.refresh()` only works for web? because when trying to use it to refresh the app's pages (for instance with `AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver`) I get an error when trying to use that command...

Comment: I see. But may I know the necessity of refreshing the android screen?

Comment: @NarendraChandratre I need to check for dynamic elements in the app, I use wait.until but sometimes it fail to locate the element for some reason… so I wondered if it is possible to refresh the screen.

Comment: I see. would like to see how wait.until has been implemented, bcz it should work for all cases. firstly check if after explicit wait its working as expected, so we can refined solution to make it work. Another strategy you might want to try would be using pooling mechanism.

Comment: @NarendraChandratre So basically I have this element (message that pops up), when trying to do wait.until It WON'T find that element unless I use xpath as the locator... implemented as: 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(MobileBy.xpath("<xPath>")));

When trying to do locate by MobileBy.id / AccessibilityId no element is found and I get the "timer" exception..